# Python How to post form with request

Tags: python, forms, request, urllib2

I want use request to post the form with python and request 
This is form with 2 value user and pass to submit them

### can you help me pls .

```
    <form method="post" action="/maxverif/0" name="loginf" id="connect">
    <p class="title">
    Connect
    </p>
    <div class="before">
      <div class="ques">
        <div class="name">Mail :</div>
        <div class="input"><input type="text" name="user"/></div>

      </div>
      <div class="question">
        <div class="name">Pass</div>
        <div class="input"><input type="password" name="pass"  /></div>
      </div></div>
    <div>
      <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" value="trens" id="connect" />
                  </div>
```

python :

```
import requests
 url = 'https://www.domains.com/store/verify/'


parameters2 = {'user': 'hhhhh@gmail.com',
              'pass': '123456'
               }

params = urllib.urlencode(parameters2)


req = urllib2.Request(url, params)


response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data=response.read()
html= etree.HTML(data)
print html
```

And when I make Print html and i see the form is not posted .
Tks

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Hi ,I make Print html and i see the form is not posted .

Comment: python print command is not for posting but for displaying/printing something. For eg: In python 2.7, consider you have a variable named as myVar = 'Hello' and if your later do print myVar it will give Hello as an output. I am sorry but you are confused and confusing others too.

Comment: Ok i understand but if i want see the result of post ?

Comment: try 'print data' instead of 'print html' and let me know what you got?

Comment: Ok tks i try to make print data they show me the html source code but when i check the <title> of page is the same as before .

Comment: When all is ok the title change to <title>Myaccount</title>

Comment: No the problem is the same .the <title> don't change we are in the page of form .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i found a solution and i make this

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'user': 'hhhhh@gmail.com', 'pass': '123456'})
opener.open('https://www.domains.com/store/verify/', login_data)
hh = opener.open('https://www.domains.com/store/verify/', login_data)
print hh.read()
```

Tks